# How to update a contentpage(GtkDrawArea) in GtkNotebook

Tags: gtk3, gtknotebook

I have a GtkWindow with a GtkNotebook. On the first page is a DrawArea. A colorgauge is drawn there, this should display a temperature. But it is not redrawn. It only works when I move the mouse over it. Outside of the GtkNotebook widget it works fine.

[Colorgauge Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpkHy.png)

How can I solve this?

PS: I'am using GTK3 and C on RPi4 with Raspbian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
g_signal_connect(notebook, "draw", G_CALLBACK(DrawNB),NULL); //in the main
gtk_widget_queue_draw(GtkWidget notebook); //after drawing the DrawArea
```

and a Draw-Method:

```
gboolean DrawNB(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data){return FALSE}
```